# How to add partial text search functionality in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to add partial text Search functionality. Can anyone suggest me how to add partial text search functionality in mongodb using nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, you're looking for a partial text match in multiple columns?

If I'm understanding you I believe you could use `$or` with a `$regex` for each field in which you're interested in matching.

You can use a text match with forward slash.  For example if the search term is "mongodb" you could say `"$regex": /mongodb/` and it would search a field for that phrase.

```
{
    $or: [
        {"field_1": {"$regex": YOUR_SEARCH_STRING} },
        {"field_2": {"$regex": YOUR_SEARCH_STRING} }
    ]
}
```

I'm new to Stack Overflow so if this isn't what you're looking for let me know and I can try to answer more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$regex` for partial text search functionality. Which is what I believe you are looking for.

[MongoDB $regex Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: If I want to search multiple partial text search columns, then how can I use this regex